# Finding nth-child of siblings via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Let's say I have two tables that look like this:

```
TH   TH   TH   TH  
TD   TD   TD   TD  
TD   TD   TD   TD
```

and

```
TH   TH   TH   TH  
TH   TD   TD   TD  
TH   TD   TD   TD
```

I'd like to select the 3rd column in each.

At first I was using nth-child as such:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

But that's not going to work, as 3rd TD is in a different column in each table.

What I need in pseudo code is 'get the 3rd TD *or* TH in each row'.

I assume I need to use $.siblings but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$('table tr :nth-child(3)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

It sets the background color of the 3rd column to 'red' (works for both tables).

Note that there is a space between `tr` and `:nth-child(3)`, and no `td` in front of `:nth-child(3)`.

You can [check out this site](http://jsbin.com/uwinu3/edit) for sample code and experiment with it.

Comment: ah! a space. Big difference between 'tr:nth-child()' and 'tr :nth-child()'! That helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `$('table tr *:nth-child(3)')`

The [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector selects elements that are the n<sup>th</sup> child of their parent, regardless of how many siblings are matched by the selector.

You're (incorrectly) describing the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector.

Comment: Actually, he's describing something that doesn't exist as a selector at all.  `table tr td:eq(3)` would return the fourth (0 based index for eq) td in the table inside of a tr, and no others.

Comment: tr:nth-child(3) returns the 3rd TR. I need to return the 3rd child of the TR. But that child may be a TD or TH

Comment: @DA: Then you need to write `tr *:nth-child(3)`.

Comment: Thanks, SLaks! The space/asterisk) was the key.